# Efficient way to search mobile number in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have about 1,000,000 mobile numbers in a MySQL table. I want to search some mobile number with database mobile number.

This is my Test Table

```
|    mobile_no      |  

|    9912345678     |    
|    9912345672     |    
|    9712345673     |    
|    9912345674     |    
|    9312345675     |    
|    9912345676     |   
|    9912345677     |   
|    8912345678     |    
|    9912345679     |   
|    9912345670     |   
|    9412345671     |
```

With 1,000,000 mobile numbers.

Now I want to the following result:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE mobile_no IN (9912345670, 9912345675, 9912345673);
```

Can I use `WHERE IN QUERY`? Or is there any efficient way? What is the fastest way to search?

Comment: You may want to think that not everyone in the world may know what a lakh is...

Comment: @gbn IIRC it means "million" in India and neighbouring countries

Comment: You may want to add your table schema/types and some sample data to the query.

Comment: @Bojangles Afaik, 100k, not one million.

Comment: @Bojangles: I know that, but as we see not everyone does. My point has been proved...

Comment: @Bojangles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh , http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/lakh , http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lakh and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lakh all agree with Joachim - 100,000, not 1,000,000.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's helpful to this community when questions show evidence of having tried a few things, and the results of those trials.

Comment: @Mark Thank you, now I feel silly

Comment: If you want to search for a small number then use and IN statement. If you want to search for a large number then put them into a temporary table and then do a join between that temp table and the table you want to search on the mobile number field (assuming that they are in a standard format).

Answer (score 0):

Your example SQL :-

SELECT * FROM Test WHERE mobile_no IN (9912345670, 9912345675, 9912345673);

Should be quite efficient (assuming that they are numeric data type columns - if not and they are character fields then surround the values with quotes).

However make sure you have an index on the mobile_no column.